# Set dd:mm:yyyy as max value on axis in Highcharts

Tags: json, highcharts

I have a JSON data which contains date and time field.

```
{
    "Agent": "Agent1",
    "CallDate": "15.03.2018",
    "CallTime": "00:00:00",
    "SomeValue": '17'
},
{
    "Agent": "Agent1",
    "CallDate": "15.03.2018",
    "CallTime": "01:00:00",
    "SomeValue": '17'
},
{
    "Agent": "Agent1",
    "CallDate": "15.03.2018",
    "CallTime": "01:00:00",
    "SomeValue": '17'
},
```

And so on...

Based on this data I created a basic area chart in Highcharts. The thing is that Highcharts automatically scales the axis according to given values. But I want it to be fixed.

I want to have `xAxis` fixed from 00:00:00 to 24:00:00 regardless of given data.

I tried something like this:

```
xAxis:
{
    min: '00:00'00',
    max: '24:00:00',
},
```

But it is not working. Also I tried to convert this to seconds:

```
xAxis:
{
    min: 0,
    max: 1440,
},
```

and it kind of works.. but now it is showing me a values in seconds. For example if I have a data with interval up to 23:00:00, the rest will be displayed in seconds on the axis, like 1420  1430, etc...

[image]

Comment: In my opinion, the easiest solution here would be to convert everything to milliseconds, then use `xAxis: {type: 'datetime', min: 0, max: 86400000}`

Comment: It's not working. There is no chart and xAxis values are still in milliseconds.

Comment: Please share your code, preferably in the form of a jsfiddle or something like that, outside of that, there is not much I can do to help.

Comment: @ewolden It is a bit hard because I integrated Highcharts into ExtJS Framework. But I will try...

Comment: You should use datetime axis - so you should convert dates to miliseconds and then set min and max also in miliseconds. To format axis labels to have a specific date format use https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.format